# Organizing daily Excel data into xarray dataset

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-xarray

Let's say I want to use xarray to work on some daily weather data, organized in a way that is similar to this example from xarray's documentation:

[image]

However, the data is provided to me in multiple Excel files where *each file contains data for one day*. File names contain the date information, and the files look like this toy example inside:

```
X  Y  Temp  Prec
1  1    21    34
1  2    24    4
1  3    22    35
2  1    23    36
```

I'm able to read the files into pandas dataframes:

```
for f in files:
  datestring = f.split('.')[0]
  date = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y%m%d')

  df = pd.read_excel(f, 0)
  df['Date'] = date
```

I can make a big dataframe with all the data (`dfAll.append(df)`) and convert between dataframes and datasets (`xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)`). However, I'm not able to re-index and organize my dataset as the image depicts. My dataset ends up looking like the following:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (index: 120)
Coordinates:
  * index         (index) int64 106 107 108 109 ...
Data variables:
    X             (index) float64 1 1 1 2 ...
    Y             (index) float64 1 2 3 1 ...
    Temp          (index) float64 21 24 22 23 ...
    Prec          (index) float64 34 40 35 36 ...
    Date          (index) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-02 2017-01-02 2017-01-02 ...
```

How can I reorganize my data like the example? Which operations should be done in pandas and which in xarray? Basically I would like to have the date, X, and Y as labels, and the Temp & Prec data as my variables.

Answer (score 2):

To make `xarray.Dataset.from_dataframe` do the right thing, you need to add columns you want to turn into dimensions into a `MultiIndex` on the DataFrame.

For your example, try: `xarray.Dataset.from_dataframe(df.set_index(['X', 'Y', 'Date'])`.

Comment: I have a similar problem to this one, could you help me out with it? Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58358170/5838180