# How to concatenate multiple csv to xarray and define coordinates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, python-xarray

I have multiple csv-files, with the same rows and columns and their contained data varies depending on the date. Each csv-file is affiliated with a different date, listed in its name, e.g. `data.2018-06-01.csv`. A minimal example of my data looks like that: I have the 2 files, `data.2018-06-01.csv` and `data.2019-06-01.csv`, that respectively contain

```
user_id, weight, status
001, 70, healthy
002, 90, healthy
```

and

```
user_id, weight, status
001, 72, healthy
002, 103, obese
```

**My Question**: How can I concatenate the csv-files into a xarray and also define that the coordinates of the xarray are `user_id` and `date`?

I tried the following code

```
df_all = [] 
date_arr = []

for f in [`data.2018-06-01.csv`, `data.2019-06-01.csv`]:
  date = f.split('.')[1]
  df = pd.read_csv(f)
  df_all.append(df)
  date_arr.append(date)

x_arr = xr.concat([df.to_xarray() for df in df_all], coords=[date_arr, 'user_id'])
```

but `coords=[...]` leads to an error. What can I do insted? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Recall that although it introduces labels in the form of dimensions, coordinates and attributes on top of raw `NumPy`-like arrays, `xarray` is inspired by and borrows heavily from `pandas`. So, to answer the question you can proceed as follows.

```
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Get the list of all the csv files in data path
csv_flist = glob(data_path + "/*.csv") 

df_list = []
for _file in csv_flist:
    # get the file name from the data path
    file_name = _file.split("/")[-1]
    
    # extract the date from a file name, e.g. "data.2018-06-01.csv"
    date = file_name.split(".")[1]
    
    # read the read the data in _file
    df = pd.read_csv(_file)
    
    # add a column date knowing that all the data in df are recorded at the same date
    df["date"] = np.repeat(date, df.shape[0])
    df["date"] = df.date.astype("datetime64[ns]") # reset date column to a correct date format
    
    # append df to df_list
    df_list.append(df)
```

Let's check e.g. the first `df` in `df_list`

```
print(df_list[0])

    status  user_id  weight       date
0  healthy        1      72 2019-06-01
1    obese        2     103 2019-06-01
```

Concatenate all the `df`s along `axis=0`

```
df_all = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True).sort_index()
print(df_all)

    status  user_id  weight       date
0  healthy        1      72 2019-06-01
1    obese        2     103 2019-06-01
2  healthy        1      70 2018-06-01
3  healthy        2      90 2018-06-01
```

Set the index of `df_all` to a multiIndex of two levels with `levels[0] = "date"` and `levels[1]="user_id"`.

```
data = df_all.set_index(["date", "user_id"]).sort_index()
print(data)

                     status  weight
date       user_id                 
2018-06-01 1        healthy      70
           2        healthy      90
2019-06-01 1        healthy      72
           2          obese     103
```

Subsequently, you can convert the resulting `pandas.DataFrame` into an `xarray.Dataset` using `.to_xarray()` as follows.

```
xds = data.to_xarray()
print(xds)

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (date: 2, user_id: 2)
Coordinates:
  * date     (date) datetime64[ns] 2018-06-01 2019-06-01
  * user_id  (user_id) int64 1 2
Data variables:
    status   (date, user_id) object 'healthy' 'healthy' 'healthy' 'obese'
    weight   (date, user_id) int64 70 90 72 103
```

Which will fully answer the question.

Comment: Thanks! I am no longer working on this task and would need to dig into my old code to test your suggestion, which unfortunately I don't have the time for. But if I happen to do this in the future I will accept your answer as the correct one for my question!

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
    import glob
    import pandas as pd

    path=(r'ur file')
    all_file = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
    li = []
    for filename in all_file:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)
    frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Could you please include a brief explanation with the code?

Comment: I have faced a problem with the image dataset. Could You please have a look at my code and help me to solve this problem. ‘’https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72156287/sample-size-valueerror-a-must-be-greater-than-0-unless-no-samples-are-taken?noredirect=1#comment127491266_72156287’’